# Mouse weird behavior at startup

Tags: boot, mouse, bug-reporting

When I boot Ubuntu and I click anywhere when it's not fully "loaded", my MouseDown event is stuck. I can still move my mouse but can't click anywhere (mouse is stuck on "drag/mousedown"). When I unplug and replug my mouse, it fixes the problem. Any clue?

Comment: Try replacing the mouse entirely.

Comment: @heynnema My mouse works well with Windows and it only happens when Ubuntu is still in loading state at startup. Don't seems to be a mouse issue here.

Comment: Don't know until you try another mouse.

Comment: Try to stop trying to use the mouse when the OS is loading. Not sure why you would in the first place.

Comment: @David If I loggin and I click anywhere in the first 5 seconds. My mouse will hang on until I unplug and replug.

Comment: FYI, last update of Ubuntu fixed the behavior :)